# Gulp append file to one of the stream sources

Tags: javascript, gulp

Take the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task('css', function(cb) {
    gulp
        .src( 'assets/css/{main,compat}.styl' )
        .pipe(styl())
        .pipe(base64({
            baseDir: 'icons/',
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['Safari >= 8']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( 'assets/css/' ))
        .pipe(csso())
        //.pipe(gzip())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( 'assets/css/' ))
        .on('end', function() {
            cb()
        })
});
```

Suppose I want to append the contents of '/assets/css/custom.css' to the contents of *main.css only*, before `.pipe(csso())`, and continue as normal (with main.css, and compat.css) afterwards.

What is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One approach, in order to have only one flow, would be to require [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-filter) and then do something like this:

```js
gulp.task('css', function() {
    var stylusOnly = filter(['**/*.styl']);
    var notCompact = filter(['*', '!assets/css/compat.css']);

    return gulp
        .src( ['assets/css/{main,compat}.styl', '/assets/css/custom.css'] )
        .pipe(stylusOnly)
        .pipe(styl())
        .pipe(base64({
            baseDir: 'icons/',
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['Safari >= 8']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( 'assets/css/' ))
        .pipe(stylusOnly.restore())
        .pipe(notCompact)
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(notCompact.restore())
        .pipe(csso())
        //.pipe(gzip())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( 'assets/css/' ));
});
```